# DOS function 1 assembly(8086) issue

Tags: assembly, intel, dos, x86-16

As far as I know, dos function 1 waits for an input character and puts it in register AL.

```
mov al,1h
int 21h
```

This does not work for me. It does not wait for an input, just inserts a random ascii into AL.

If I modify AL with AH it works as it should.

```
mov ah,1h
```

Why is that?

Comment: that's how the `int 21h` service is implemented by your DOS vendor, the service number is expected in `AH`, not `AL`. Check your DOS services [documentation](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-1.html), whichever you use. And if it says "AL=1", then replace it with some more correct one.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Ralf Brown's excellent interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2552.htm), the function has to be in `ah` when calling, the `al` in this case is simply used to hold the return value:

```
DOS 1+ - READ CHARACTER FROM STANDARD INPUT, WITH ECHO
    AH = 01h
Return:
    AL = character read
```

So your code should really be:

```
mov  ah,01h
int  21h
;; al should now contain the character.
```

By calling `int 21` after setting only `al`, you are basically using whatever value happened to be in `ah` beforehand. That's unlikely to end well :-)